# Is there any way to show a tooltip for points which are not visible on the chart in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart

I have a line chart that has a minimum value for the Y-axis. Sometimes the data goes under this minimum value and I don't want to stretch the chart because of this one point, but I want to have the tooltip to show the data when I move my cursor to the value in the X-axis.

I've created a codepen about the problem: [codepen](https://codepen.io/BergkampHUN/pen/vYWdKJE)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["R", "B", "Y", "G", "P", "O"],
    datasets: [
      {
         label: "# of Votes",
         data: [12, 13, 11, 12, 9, 13]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        min: 10
      },
    },
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'nearest',
      axis: 'x',
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `interaction.mode: 'x'` as explained [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#x).

Please take a look at your amended code below and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["R", "B", "Y", "G", "P", "O"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "# of Votes",
      data: [12, 13, 11, 12, 9, 13]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        min: 10
      }      
    },
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'x'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! But this solution will show the tooltips only when the pointer is really on the data point on the X axis. I would like to keep the 'nearest' value for interaction